# How to make Mathematica show small and large results?

Tags: numerics, numerical-value

I have two equations with `x=r+Log[-1+r]` and `v=(1-1/r)/r^3` forms. When I substitute `r=1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001`, Mathematica shows `x=Indeterminate` and `v=0`. But I know that the results are `x=-201.6274881834760201935832480122240502688969309993320218909328552851463896516070182607677539478846503` and `v=0.9999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999999997000000000000*10^(-88)`. How to make Mathematica show these small and large results? I will be really thankful if someone help.

Comment: How did you get -201 for x ? Could you please double-check ?

Comment: @Lotus I have obtained these results from Maple. I am sure about them.

Comment: See `SetPrecision` and [here](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/guide/PrecisionAndAccuracyControl.html), i.e. `r=SetPrecision[1.0000…01,100]`. alternatively, you can also specify the precision using ``r=1.000…01`100``

Comment: You can also manually append more zeros to `r`, as in `r=1.000…00100…` - the more you add, the more digits the result will have. Essentially, Maple is assuming the number you gave it has infinite precision, while Mathematica accurately tracks the precision throughout the calculation.

Comment: @LukasLang Thanks for the reply, but this does not work. In Maple also it is required to specify the precision. I used "evalf(eq,100)" in Maple. But I do not know how I can solve this problem in Mathematica.

Comment: Yes it does: [Image](https://i.imgur.com/30e15zP.jpg) - or am I misunderstanding what you want?

Comment: @Mehrab: How can you be "sure about Maple"? The first function `x[r]=r+Log[-1+r] `has a singularity for `r->1`. Mathematica finds `r + Log[-1 + r] /. r -> 1(*-\[Infinity]*)`

Comment: @LukasLang Oh yes you are right. Thank you very much for your help :)

Comment: @UlrichNeumann That is not a singularity. See the image that Lukas Lang posted in the previous comment and https://imgur.com/a/ULhWnPV.

Comment: @Mehrab: Unfortunately the image isn't available. But the logarithm has a singulatity if its argument tends to zero.(Weisstein Mathworld)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Lucas Lang said in his first answer, Mathematica gives the same as Maple:

```
r = SetPrecision[1.0000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000000001, 100]    
x = r + Log[-1 + r] 
v = (1 - 1/r)/r^3
```

-201.62748818348

1.00000000000*10^-88